PgHero permission denied for function pg_stat_statements_reset in Azure
I dumped and restored my database from AWS RDS to Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server (PostgreSQL version 14.13) and even though PgHero used to work correctly, in Azure it throws permission denied error when running bin/rake pghero:capture_query_stats:
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_stat_statements_reset
CONTEXT:  SQL function "pg_stat_statements_reset" statement 1
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:48:in `exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:41:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:47:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:765:in `block in log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:756:in `log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:46:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero/methods/basic.rb:104:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero/methods/query_stats.rb:94:in `reset_instance_query_stats'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero/methods/query_stats.rb:152:in `block in capture_query_stats'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero/methods/query_stats.rb:151:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero/methods/query_stats.rb:151:in `capture_query_stats'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero.rb:195:in `block in capture_query_stats'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero.rb:264:in `block in each_database'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero.rb:262:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero.rb:262:in `each_database'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/pghero.rb:192:in `capture_query_stats'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pghero-3.3.3/lib/tasks/pghero.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

The function's creation statement is:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pghero.pg_stat_statements_reset(userid oid, dbid oid, queryid bigint) RETURNS void AS
$$
  SELECT public.pg_stat_statements_reset(userid, dbid, queryid);
$$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;

I tried dropping schema pghero and recreating it following the permissions guide but it keeps throwing the same error.
I also tried granting access to the function using:
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pghero.pg_stat_statements_reset(oid, oid, bigint) TO pghero;
and
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.pg_stat_statements_reset(oid, oid, bigint) TO pghero;
If I connect to the database with the pghero user using psql, I can execute the function without errors.
Any help appreciated.

Everything is configured according to pghero docs. The pghero user has all the necessary permissions to access and use everything in pghero schema.


ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_stat_statements_reset

The above error you are getting is because of the pg_stat_statements_reset  function need Superuser privileges. pg_stat_statements_reset   this function can only be executed by superusers. Access may be granted to others using GRANT.
In Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server, Superuser privileges are not available to server admin accounts for security reasons.
The alternative solution you can use try is Use the Query Store:

In Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server offers a different way to monitor query execution statistics like Query Store. To prevent performance overhead, it is recommended to utilize only one mechanism, either the pg_stat_statements extension or the Query Store

To enable Query Store follow below steps:
Go to your Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server >> Select  Server parameters  in the  Settings  section >> Search  pg_qs.query_capture_mode >> Set the value to  TOP  / ALL, depending on you need >>  Save.


Thank you for your reply, the documentation quote states that To prevent performance overhead, it is recommended to utilize only one mechanism, either the pg_stat_statements extension or the Query Store but since pg_stat_statements_reset cannot be utilized, how can I use pg_stat_statemets extension?

check this Document to understand the Use of pg_stat_statements in Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server.

The linked document does not mention any inability to use pg_stat_statements_reset or any blocked feature/operation of pg_stat_statements extension in general. Query Store an an alternative does not provide a solution since the goal is to implement PgHero which seems to not be possible with Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server.
